# Displaying Two Different Variables On The 7 segment LED Display with the Help Of A Switch - VHDL and FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have been trying to display two different variables on the 7 segment led display on a spartan 3 fpga using VHDL language. This is for my final year project at uni and I'm really struggling. Can someone pleeeeeaaasssseee help? :(

Comment: Add your best effort code to the question and maybe someone can give you pointers how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Switch is a C reserved word.  For VHDL you'll want to use case instead.

Comment: Okay thanx but by switch I meant the switch on the fpga and not switch as a function.

Comment: But of course you did!  Take the hint and read up on case, or selected signal assignments, or if statements, or maybe just try posting some actual code for review.

Comment: U3: Mod60Counter port map (
  Reset => Reset,
  Clk => Clk,
  Dir => iSecDir,
  En => iSecEn,
  CarryOut => iCarrySec,
  Bcd0 => open,
  Bcd1 => open
  );
  
  iSecDir <= '1' when SetRun = '1';

  iSecEn <= iCarry50M when SetRun = '1' else
      (SecAdj and iCarry25M); 

 U4: Mod60Counter port map (
  Reset => Reset,
  Clk => Clk,
  Dir => iMinDir,
  En => iMinEn,
  CarryOut => iCarryMin,
  Bcd0 => iMin0,
  Bcd1 => iMin1
  );
 
  
  iMinDir <= '1' when SetRun = '1' else
       MinUpDown;

  iMinEn <= iCarrySec when SetRun = '1' else
      (MinAdj and iCarry25M);

Comment: U5: Mod24Counter port map (
  Reset => Reset24,
  Clk => Clk,
  Dir => iHourDir,
  En => iHourEn,
  CarryOut => open,
  Bcd0 => iHour0,
  Bcd1 => iHour1
  );
       
  Reset24 <= '1' when (iHour1 = "0010" and iHour0 = "0100") else
      Reset;

  iHourDir <= '1' when SetRun = '1' else
       HourUpDown;
  
  iHourEn <= iCarryMin when SetRun = '1' else
      (HourAdj and iCarry25M);

Comment: I am making a prototype of a Central Heating Controller, I made a clock that displays on the Spartan-3, but I am having a problem with displaying the temperature display on the same 4digits 7segment display. I want it to be a situation where I can flick a switch and the 4digits 7segment display would display the temperature. The code shows the configuration of the clock.

Comment: I wasn't able to include the code for the day counter due to the character limitation. It's not really needed for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you:

```
if (Swtich_1 = '1') then
  Seven_Seg <= Date_Time;
else
  Seven_seg <= Temperature;
end if;
```

that is all you need :)

There are a few things you have to be careful about

- Make sure you denounce the switch and it is clean
- Make a simple seven segment converter to handle the data (simple case statement should do or a proces than you can find searching the net).

Hope it helps....